# How to include both taxonamy and content type in a single views exposed search form

Tags: search

I need to add an exposed search block using views in the site. Which searches the data in content types and taxonomy terms that i specified in my views filter. Any way to do it.

Comment: A view can only query one entity type at a time, so I wouldn't have thought so. If you can add some information to the question someone will probably be able to tell you for sure

Comment: I have 10 content types and 8 taxonomy vocabularies. Need to a create an exposed search form block which includes 6 content types and 5 taxonomy vocabulary contents.